# Understanding jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem and not really sure what is going on. I have been copy pasting some code from various sources in attempt to get something cool to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(function() {
    bootstrapActive = false;

    ...a lot more code...
</script>

... more code

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $j(function($) {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

It used to only be the `$j(function)` with the tabs. When I added the first `$j` function seen here the tabs no longer work.

Is this a property of jQuery? Could someone help me out? I am not sure what the right questions are to ask. Any suggestions?

Comment: more than likely there is an error in the code you added that made the tabs stop working.

Comment: So you've added the `...a lot more code...` section, and now it doesn't work. Could you please explain how anyone can help if you edit the only relevant code out of your question?

Comment: if you are not sure how the code work, copy it exactly how it is on the original

Comment: put your project in jsfiddle.net service, and then you can show to another people your troubles.

Comment: @ibu correction: if you are not sure how the code works, *don't use it*

Comment: nope, no correction @chris, most don't know how jquery works but still use it

Comment: @Ibu: And what Chris is saying is you *shouldn't* use it unless you understand it.

Answer (score 3):

> I have been copy pasting some code from various sources in attempt to get something cool to work

O RLY?

The answer is to go through, bit by bit, and understand the code that you've copied and pasted, instead of putting it in willy-nilly.

Remove everything, start fresh, and add in small sections of code. Once you understand it, and it works, move on to adding more features and code.

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery` is a JavaScript object. Like most JS frameworks, it creates an alias of `jQuery` as `$`. That then allows you to do stuff like `$('#something')` instead of having to use `jQuery('#something')`.

However, jQuery is also designed to be able to be used with other JS frameworks, so it has a "no conflict" mode, that essentially restores the `$` to the other framework (Prototype for example). You enable "no conflict" mode by doing something like:

```
var someVar - jQuery.noConflict();
...
someVar('#something')
```

In your code `someVar` is `$j`. That's all.

Since you're obviously very new to jQuery, you *need* to spend some time going over the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page). Pasting code is fun and all, but you're not learning anything and in fact, you're knee deep in a recipe for disaster.